# Mac Color options for HP U28 4K HDR

Tags: mac, display, colors, external-display, hdr

I was wondering what color options I should pick for [this](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-u28-4k-hdr-monitor) monitor. Because this monitor has specific color requirements and it's one of its selling points so I don't want to miss out.

Here are all the options I can see now from system prefrences:
[image]

Comment: The monitor itself might have cool features, but without a color profile and GPU that supports them, those features are superfluous. I would recommend getting a color calibration device like a [SpyderX](https://spyderx.datacolor.com) that can calibrate your system by creating a color profile that factors in all of those factors. That’s how the pros do it.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 -  Personally, I use the X-Rite i1Display Pro [having bought two other cheaper ones before & discarded them], but it's down to personal preference in the end. Expect to pay $£€ 150 - 250 for one that is worth the cost. Half the money is in the software, the hardware is the same. There's a freeware software calibration alternative, which I prefer to use sometimes (especially on TVs rather than monitors), [DisplayCAL](https://displaycal.net)… but you already need to have bought at least the entry-level hard/software package first, & it's not as comprehensive for display models.

Comment: @Tetsujin is there any other software you think I should use for my new monitor?

Comment: People tend to use either the one that comes with the hardware, or DisplayCAL. there's not really anything else* - & it cannot be done without the colorimeter hardware investment. [*There's software dedicated to television screens, Calman - but that's **really** expensive]

Answer (score 1):

"specific color requirements" include a profile, designed for that specific display & also the computer & GPU driving it.

It will have been supplied with a generic profile for the display type by the manufacturer, but without a hardware colorimeter to calibrate & profile that *specific* display, that's as accurate as you can get.

BTW, you don't really need to know what *any* of those numbers or characteristics mean. Consider them "rocket science" & just leave them alone.